# Cannot See Images Uploaded To A Folder On The Server

Tags: php, mysql

Hi, I have a problem with uploading files in my server. This is my code:

```
                   <?php
                   session_start();
                   $user=$_SESSION['user_level'];
                   Check if a file has been uploaded
                   if(isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {
          // Make sure the file was sent without errors
                   if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] == 0) {
         // Connect to the database
                   $dbLink = new mysqli('$host', '$username', '$pass', '$tbl_name');
                   if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                   die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
                   }

             // Gather all required data
           //$id= mysql_insert_id(); 
                  $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
                  $mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']);
                  $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string
                  (file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']));
                  $size = intval($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size']);

            // Create the SQL query
                  $query = "
                  INSERT INTO files (email,name,type,size,content)
                  VALUES ('$user','$name', '$mime', $size, '$data')";

           // Execute the query
                  $result = $dbLink->query($query);}}
          ?>
                  <?php 
                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
            "/home/u152912911/public_html/upload" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
                ?>

                  <?php
                  if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] > 0)
                  {
                  echo "Apologies, an error has occurred.";
                  echo "Error Code: " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"];
                  }
                  else
                  {
                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
                  "/home/u152912911/public_html/upload" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"] 
                  ["name"]);
                  }
                  if (($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/DOC")
                  || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
                  || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/png" )
                  && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] < 10000))
                  {
                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
          "/home/u152912911/public_html/upload" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

              ECHO "Files Uploaded Succesfully";
              echo'<script type="text/javascript">

          window.location.href ="resume2.php"
                  </script>';
                   }
                  else
                  {
                  }
                  echo "Your Resume was Successfully Upload";
                  ?>
```

I have a folder named "upload" wherein it will store all the files uploaded by the user. My objective is to store the file in mysql and in the "upload" folder. The storing of file works fine with no error messages but I can't see the uploaded file inside the "upload" folder. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is possible that you do not have the correct permissions to upload the file to that directory. If you are on windows try changing the permissions to 777 on the upload directory.

Comment: check you have enough privilege to modify the folder.

Answer (score 3):

```
"/home/u152912911/public_html/upload" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]
```

You are missing a trailing slash `/` after `upload`. Change it to:

```
"/home/u152912911/public_html/upload/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]
```

As it is, the file is being saved as a file name with the prefix `upload` in the `public_html` directory.

If possible you should use a relative path for portability, there is a good chance that simply

```
"upload/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]
```

...would suffice.

## HOWEVER

you should not be using `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` directly like this. Consider what would happen if the user sent the string `../index.php` as the file name - the user would be able to overwrite your `index.php` file. Also, consider what would happen if two users uploaded a file named `picture.jpg` - the second upload would overwrite the first.

Instead you should use a name for the file that you create yourself - it is not safe to rely on user input like this.

Comment: thank you! it is now working! :) i will also consider your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 2):

You forget a slash:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
          "/home/u152912911/public_html/upload" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

should be

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],
          "/home/u152912911/public_html/upload/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

Also, check the return value for succes, don't assume it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permission provided to the folder where you are storing the files.

Answer (score 0):

if its working fine on local host and giving problem in online testing then ask the server-host to change the folder permissions to 777.